# Prove that $\lim|x_n| < a$ for all $a > 0$ implies $\lim|x_n| = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers.

I am wondering we can formally prove that:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|x_n| < a$$

for all $a > 0$, implies

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|x_n| = 0$$

Comment: Clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty} |x_n|\geq 0$, so what non-negative number satisfies being smaller than every other postive number?

Comment: Note that denote $b=lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|$, then $0\leq b<a$, for all $a>0$, so by contradiction, $b=0.$

Comment: Instead of $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|x_n|<a$, could you possibly want something like "eventually, $|x_n|$ is always less than $a$ (but we're not assuming the limit exists yet)"? In that case, it's still true that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|x_n|=0$, but it's less trivial.

Comment: What's more,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|x_n|<a\quad\text{for all }a>0\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=0
$$

Comment: robjohn's comment is a rephrasing of (a very slightly weaker version of) Lopsy's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|x_n|$. Then $0\le L<a $  for all $a>0$. Suppose $L>0$. Then $\frac{L}{2}>0$ and so using $a=\frac{L}{2}$ gives 
$$L<a=\frac{L}{2}\Rightarrow L<0$$
which is a contradiction

Comment: No need to divide by $2$, since strict inequality is already assumed: $L<L$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Sure you don't. But because when dealing with limits and a positive number pops up, we usually devide it by $2$ and use it as $\epsilon$. Also this covers the case $L\le a$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\varepsilon > 0$ is the limit under consideration.
Choosing $a=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ gives us a contradiction from your first equation.
Therefore $\varepsilon$ has to be smaller or equal to zero.

Now, from your first equation, and because there is a $\delta$ such that for $n> n_0$ all the elements of $|x_n|$ belong to $]0, \delta[$, we have to have the limit of $|x_n|$ belonging to $[0, \delta]$, i.e. it has to be non-negative.

The only non negative number which is smaller or equal to zero is zero.

q.e.d.

Comment: @Stefan Hansen, thank you for your edit! I have to learn how to LaTeX in here! // I dont actually think "Nameless"'s answer, accepted as the correct one, is fully correct, as it explicitely assumes the limit has to be non-negative,( but I am not allowed to comment in there!) :S:S

Comment: No problem :) I guess you'll have to earn some more reputation in order to for you to comment on his answer. I'm sure you can do that

Comment: Its increasing already!!! :)